# ICommand в DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Доброго времени суток.

У меня имеется подобный код:

```
<ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        Style="{StaticResource lbStyle}"
        >

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:iEventControl>
                    <local:iEventControl.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Открыть таблицу" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </local:iEventControl.ContextMenu>
                </local:iEventControl>
            </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Можно ли каким-то образом в обработчике MenuItemClick получить ListBoxItem, у которого было вызвано контекстное меню? (Ну или сам ListBox, внутри которого было вызвано меню).

Написал использование Command по примеру, в данном случае почему-то не работает (DataContext установлен).

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы уверены, что `DataContext` установлен правильно? Покажите код VM.

Comment: DataContext тут не поможет. Контекстное меню, как я помню, не часть логического дерева. Нужно использовать CommandTarget

Comment: @vitidev: Хм. Может, вы и правы, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @vitidev: Странно, у меня работает вот так: http://pastebin.com/3caJsE1x. Возможно, они протягивают DataContext?

Comment: @VladD у вас контекстное меню контрола. там проблем нет. в DataTemplate работать не будет.

Comment: @vitidev: Но работает же? http://pastebin.com/SRs1UMYB

Comment: @VladD работает. Я для использования биндинга на команду в родительском контроле я использую референсы. Код, который я привел, содержит решения разных проблем, потому пришлось изменить ответ.  или оно раньше не работало в старых версиях, потому что с какой то целью пришлось городить такой огород. Впрочем до родительского DataContext это не дает добраться.

Comment: @vitidev: Ага, я помню проблему с ненаследуемым контекстом. Наверное, WPF улучшился.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37674/discussion-between-vitidev-and-vladd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если команда находится во вьюмодели пункта списка, то ничего делать не нужно - биндинг работает верно
MenuItemClick будет вызываться в классе для которого рисуется пункт списка

Если же хендлер команды находится в вьюмодели, что содержит сам список, то указать на нужное место не получается в силу того, что контекстное меню не часть логического дерева и RelativeSource не работает.

Для указания правильной команды используют различные трюки вроде таких https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu

Я же вместо плясок с бубном использую класс CommandReference

```
public class CommandReference : Freezable, ICommand
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command",
    typeof (ICommand),
    typeof (CommandReference
        ),
    new PropertyMetadata(
        OnCommandChanged));

public ICommand Command
{
    get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var commandReference = d as CommandReference;
    var oldCommand = e.OldValue as ICommand;
    var newCommand = e.NewValue as ICommand;

    if (oldCommand != null)
    {
        oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
    }
    if (newCommand != null)
    {
        newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}

#region Freezable

protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
{
    return this;
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

#endregion

#region ICommand Members

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (Command != null)
        return Command.CanExecute(parameter);
    return false;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    Command.Execute(parameter);
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

#endregion
}
```

Который позволяет в ресурсах окна/контрола задать ссылку на команду

```
<mvvm:CommandReference x:Key="ShowCommandRef" Command="{Binding ShowCommand}" />
```

то есть по отношению к DataContext окна
и вызвать его в меню

```
<MenuItem Command="{StaticResource ShowCommandRef}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Именно пункта списка?
Каким образом организовать выполнение команды, объявленной в VM?

Comment: @bodynar У вас ошибка. Нужно так <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" -  это ж не DataContext, а источник-список. Тогда в DataTemplate попадает по экземпляру содержимого списка и ваше   Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" будет указывать команду MenuItemClick в этом экземпляре. Так это работает, но похоже, что вам нужно единый обратчик для списка в который прилетит выбранный пункт.

Comment: верно подмечено. Прочитав сообщения выше тоже дошел до этого умозаключения.
Каким образом тогда организовать Command и ItemsSource?

Comment: @bodynar зависит от целей. смотря куда должен прыгать вызов команды - в метод класса пункта списка или в класс, где сам список содержится. Если в первое, то оно туда и так попадает (стоит лишь поправить ItemSource)

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы команда вызывалась в ViewModel. 
Ещё необходимо получать ListBoxItem, у которого была вызвана команда из контекстного меню.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. ListBoxItem вы не получите, вам он ни к чему, это ж команды, а не события. Вы получите обьект ассоциированный с ListBoxItem, то есть просто элемент списка, который вы указали как ItemSource

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37720/discussion-between-bodynar-and-vitidev).

Comment: Можно ли вас, @vitidev,  опять втянуть в чатик? Вопрос насчет MVVM, погряз.

Comment: @bodynar он заморожен туда писать нельзя. Как где создаются еще чаты - без понятия

Comment: есть ли какой-нибудь иной способ связаться с вами, @vitidev?

Comment: @bodynar http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new создавайте чат, приглашайте. мне некогда разбираться как там эти чаты устроены. но создать очевидно можно

Comment: Странно, при попытках создать комнату (как уникальную, так и похожую на созданную) выдает ошибку. @vitidev, пожалуй тогда создам вопрос.

Comment: @bodynar жду http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41827/discussion-between-bodynar-and-vitidev

Comment: Крутой класс =) Я им доволен.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно примерно вот так подключить менюшку из VM

```
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="Menu" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Menu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
    ...
```

`Menu` - коллекция команд, которая уже по стилям отображается как надо.